# Visual Studio: Override "Smart" indenting only for a few specific lines

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, tabs, indentation

I'm writing some vb.net code in Visual Studio. I have Smart Indenting turned on, and I want to keep it on. However, there's a section of my code that I want to use some extra indentation to outline things in a more human-readable way. I can tab over to the indent level I want, but as soon as I change to another line, the Smart indenting bumps the line back to where it "should" be.

How can I add some extra indentation to certain lines in my code WITHOUT disabling Smart Indenting altogether?

---

How I want it:

```vb
Call GetRibbon("Part")
     Call GetTab("3D Model")
          Call NewButton("Custom1")
Call GetRibbon("Assembly")
     Call GetTab("Assemble")
          Call NewButton("Custom2")
```

How VS formats it:

```vb
Call GetRibbon("Part")
Call GetTab("3D Model")
Call NewButton("Custom1")
Call GetRibbon("Assembly")
Call GetTab("Assemble")
Call NewButton("Custom2")
```

Comment: Which Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Express 2017, Version 15.9.9

Comment: Why are you using the useless `Call` keyword at all?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Good question. I don't use `Call` in my actual code, I just did it here to help communicate that these are simple calls and aren't structurally related to each other in any way. Although in hindsight I guess that should be obvious and even here the Calls weren't necessary...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to override/cancel the Smart tab logic if it's in effect for your language in the IDE (it's set in the Tabs options for your language--go to the IDE's Tools | Options menu to see it).

I think the best option you have is to hit Ctrl-Z immediately after the "smart" logic is applied. That will restore the indentation you intended.

Comment: Perfect, that does just what I need. I didn't think of the Smart indenting as an operation that I could undo. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but the `Call` keyword is a legacy of pre-.NET Visual Basic, and is not required to call subroutines in .NET. The following would be more succinct and essential:

```
GetRibbon("Part")
GetTab("3D Model")
NewButton("Custom1")
GetRibbon("Assembly")
GetTab("Assemble")
NewButton("Custom2") ' btw this can also be indented as in Jazimov's answer
```

However, pasting that repetitious code just bugged me to the point that I would suggest this

```
Sub Initialize(p1 As String, p2 As String, p3 As String)
    GetRibbon(p1)
    GetTab(p2)
    NewButton(p3)
End Sub

...

Initialize("Part", "3D Model", "Custom1")
Initialize("Assembly", "Assemble", "Custom2")
```

at which point, indentation probably would be unnecessary

You can see that `Call` is still good for some hacky ways to accomplish C#-like operations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference//statements/call-statement

Comment: I don't use Call in my actual code, I just did it here to help communicate that these are simple calls and aren't structurally related to each other in any way. Although in hindsight I guess that should be obvious and even here the Calls weren't necessary...

As for the repetition, my actual code has a lot more going on behind the scenes, and the outlining structure is much simpler than repeating "Part" for each entry under Part, "3D Model" for each entry under 3D Model, etc. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Interesting question anyway, and I never knew about explicit formatting with undo either. Thanks